# Upgrading Expo SDK from 47 to 49

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm upgrading my **Expo** from **47** to **49**. I've followed the suggestion.. and went from **47** to **48** (it worked well), and now i'm doing **48** to **49**...

And at first I was getting this reanimated error:

```
ERROR  TypeError: _ReanimatedModule.default.configureProps is not a function. (In '_ReanimatedModule.default.configureProps(Object.keys(NATIVE_THREAD_PROPS_WHITELIST), Object.keys(UI_THREAD_PROPS_WHITELIST))', '_ReanimatedModule.default.configureProps' is undefined)
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

I've added the solutions to my package.json :

```
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4"
  },
```

and now I'm getting a different error that is still related to the react reanimated... which is:

```
Error: [Reanimated] Mismatch between JavaScript part and native part of Reanimated (3.5.4 vs 3.3.0).
See `https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/troubleshooting#mismatch-between-javascript-part-and-native-part-of-reanimated` for more details., js engine: hermes
```

I've tried changing the "react-native-reanimated" to **3.3.0**... but the error persists.. right now my react native reanimated is: **"react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4"**

I also tried this:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && npm install && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-cache then running react-native start --reset-cache
```

[source](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/4736#issuecomment-1639967526).

but it didn't work either. Any clues on how to tackle this issue?